# Does PHP 7 throw an error when passing too few parameters to a function?

Tags: php, function, parameters, arguments

I'm upgrading my webapp to php7 from 5.6, and I'm suddenly getting errors when I pass too few arguments to functions.  In php 5.6 I was able to have functions with say three parameters, and I could pass two, and it would work fine.  Has anyone else run into this?  Is this new in php7?

I used to be able to pass two arguments to a function with three parameters, but suddenly I'm getting errors.

```
function displayField ($fieldname,$fieldval,$nobold)  { ... };

displayField ("testname","this value");
```

In this case I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function displayField(), 2 passed in
>   /home/cabox/workspace/php/encscripts.php on line 31 and exactly 3
>   expected in /home/cabox/workspace/php/encscripts.php:3

Is there a way around this, or do I have to find every example of passing fewer than the expected parameters and rewrite my code?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: try to add default value to function displayField ($fieldname,$fieldval,$nobold='...')  { ... };

Comment: Previous Php versions emit a warning, 7.1.0 and up look to give fatal error: https://3v4l.org/AuJ1L

Answer (score 9):

From PHP manual:

> Previously, a warning would be emitted for invoking user-defined functions with too few arguments. Now, this warning has been promoted to an Error exception. This change only applies to user-defined functions, not internal functions. For example:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php

Try to make the third parameter optional:

```
function displayField($fieldname, $fieldval, $nobold = null) { ... };
```

Comment: Great idea... thanks!  Much easier than going through all the function calls and adding default parameters.

Comment: Well into using the app now, and this solution worked perfectly.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Serhii Andriichuk What if I wanna make first param as optional, I can understand middle params can;t be set to optional without first and last, but there should be a way to set first one as optional with default value specification ?